# IllegalMonitorStateException on notify() when synchronized on an Integer

Tags: java, wait, notify, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I'm new to using wait() and notify() in Java and I'm getting an IllegalMonitorStateException.

**Main Code**

```
public class ThreadTest {

    private static Integer state = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        synchronized(state) {
            System.out.println("Starting thread");

            Thread t = new Thread(new AnotherTest());
            t.start();

            synchronized(state) {
                state = 0;
                while(state == 0) {
                    try {
                        state.wait(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("State is: " + state);
            }
        }
    }   

    public static class AnotherTest implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(state) {
                state = 1;
                state.notify();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting an IllegalMonitorStateException what state.notify() is called.  Any ideas?

**Edit**: Based on answer below here is code that works.  As a side note, I was first trying this with an enum which has the same problem of using Integer.

```
public class ThreadTest {

    private static int state = 0;
    private static Object monitor = new Object();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        synchronized(monitor) {
            System.out.println("Starting thread");

            Thread t = new Thread(new AnotherTest());
            t.start();

            state = 0;
            while(state == 0) {
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Waiting " + (5 - i) + " Seconds");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    monitor.wait(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("State is: " + state);
        }
    }   

    public static class AnotherTest implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(monitor) {
                state = 1;
                monitor.notify();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This

```
private static Integer state = 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
private static Integer state = Integer.valueOf(0);
```

The invocation of `valueOf(0)` returns a reference to an `Integer` object, call it A.

You then do

```
synchronized(state) {
```

your thread acquires the lock on the object referenced by `state`, currently that is A.

You then do

```
state = 1;
```

which is equivalent to

```
state = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

which gives you a different reference to an `Integer` object, call it B, and assigns it to `state`. When you then call

```
state.notify();
```

you're invoking `notify()` on an object, B, for which your thread doesn't own the monitor. You can't call `notify` or `wait` on objects for which your thread doesn't own the monitor.

Comment: This illustrates why it's kind of pointless to use `wait/notify` on immutable objects if your code depends on changing the value of the waited-on object...

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something pretty straight forward.