# Getting illegal monitor state exception on notify

Tags: java, multithreading

The below program  is supposed to print even and odd numbers by two different threads but I am getting illegal monitor exception on notify method in the below code :

```
public class oddeven {
    static volatile Integer t = 0;

    public static void main(String as[]) {
        oddrunnable or = new oddrunnable(t);
        evenrunnable er = new evenrunnable(t);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(or, "odd");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(er, "even");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}

class oddrunnable implements Runnable {
    Integer t;

    public oddrunnable(Integer t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        synchronized (t) {
            while (true) {

                if (t % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        t.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Current thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                t++;
                t.notify();
            }
        }
    }

}

class evenrunnable implements Runnable {
    Integer t;

    public evenrunnable(Integer t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        synchronized (t) {
            while (true) {

                if (t % 2 != 0) {
                    try {
                        t.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Current thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                t++;
                t.notify(); // <-------------------exception on this line
            }
        }

    }

}
```

the notify method is called on the synchronized object itself. Not sure why this is coming :

```
    Current thread id even
Exception in thread "even" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at evenrunnable.run(oddeven.java:86)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733718/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-notify similar question. accepted answer explains it well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integers in java wrapper are immutable, so as soon as you do `t++`, you are going to assign a new Integer object which you didn't took lock against and hence you get `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Instead of Integer, use `AtomicInteger` and then use `incrementAndGet` api to increment the value of counter.

Comment: for Integer objects t++ is an equivalent for t = Integer.valueOf(t.intValue() + 1);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in using Integer object for synchronization and than doing increment(++) operation on it. I think its creating new integer object and than all the synchronized logic is going for toss. I am not sure about it as while debugging your code, eclipse was not showing whether it created new object.

A better alternative is to use some wrapper object around your integer or AtomicInteger class. Here is your code with AtomicInteger class used

```
public class oddeven {
    static volatile AtomicInteger t = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String as[]) {
        oddrunnable or = new oddrunnable(t);
        evenrunnable er = new evenrunnable(t);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(or, "odd");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(er, "even");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}

class oddrunnable implements Runnable {
    AtomicInteger t;

    public oddrunnable(AtomicInteger t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        synchronized (t) {
            while (true) {

                if (t.intValue() % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        t.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Current thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                t.incrementAndGet();
                t.notify();
            }
        }
    }

}

class evenrunnable implements Runnable {
    AtomicInteger t;

    public evenrunnable(AtomicInteger t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        synchronized (t) {
            while (true) {

                if (t.intValue() % 2 != 0) {
                    try {
                        t.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Current thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                t.incrementAndGet();

                t.notify(); // <-------------------exception on this line
            }
        }

    }

}
```